# How to fix a line at the end of table with Datatables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using Datatables and at the end of the table I have a line with a total of each columns and I would like to fix this line at the end of the table for when I'll use the sorting option this line stay at the end. You can see on the picture the line `Island Total` is this line I would like to fix at the of the table. For the table I get the value by AJAX request and the total is calculate is the javascript. I know I can use the `footerCallBack` option include in DataTables but I can't edit the total line with this method therefore I can't use the `footerCallBack`.

JS for the table :

```
var data_use = [["Le Gold", 77.5, 10190, 789666], ["Bois Rouge", 68.9, 10031, 691571], ["Total île", 73.2, 20221, 1481237]];

$('#datatable').DataTable({
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
    "lengthMenu" : [[5, 10, 20, 30, -1], [5, 10, 20, 30, "All"]],
    "iDisplayLength" : -1,
    data : data_use,
    columns : column_name,
    dom : 'lfrtip',
    responsive : true,
    destroy : true,
    searching: true,
});
```

[image]

Comment: You are using row as summary row? Maybe footer would be more suitable in this case? You can try to read about it [here](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/51510/how-to-enable-table-footer)

Comment: @dganenco please read the post I explain why I can't use this

Comment: What do you mean with "I can't edit the total line"? You can access each column's data and work with it, check the second example on the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/footerCallback)

Comment: And that is yet another perfect example of why you should **never** use external `$.ajax()` call to populate DataTable and prefer [`ajax`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option instead. The latter would give you flexibility not only transform AJAX response, but allow to enjoy the rest of API that would allow to populate effortlessly totals either on the bottom line, or in the `<footer>`.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I'm using a external AJAX call because I use the same data for anther part of the project.

Comment: @Sebastianb In the project the user  must have the choice to edit the data in the table as well as the total line, that's why I can't use the `footerCallBack`.

Comment: @SebCollard : Even if there's something **on the same page** with DataTables that uses exactly the same data it doesn't seem that hitting that endpoint twice would be such a big price for flexibility.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest workaround for your case that I can think of is to filter 'totals' out of your table data and append those to the bottom of the table (modify DOM) upon each re-draw.

It does not obviate my above comments and doesn't seem to be very good solution, nevertheless, does exactly what's expected:

```js
//src data
const data_use = [{basin:'Beaufond',yield:66,area:5183,production:342041},{basin:'Boid Rouge',yield:72.1,area:4848,production:349530},{basin:'Grand-Bois',yield:80.5,area:3519,production:238200},{basin:'Island Total',yield:73.3,area:20220,production:1481237},{basin:'Le Gol',yield:82.9,area:4282,production:354983},{basin:'Savanna',yield:63.4,area:2388,production:151483}];
//columns config
const column_name = [{title:'Basin',data:'basin'},{title:'Yield (T/ha)',data:'yield'},{title:'Surface area (ha)',data:'area'},{title:'Production (T)',data:'production'},{title:'',data:()=>'<button>Edit</button>'}];

//datatables initialization
$('#datatable').DataTable({
    sPaginationType : "full_numbers",
    lengthMenu : [[5, 10, 20, 30, -1], [5, 10, 20, 30, "All"]],
    iDisplayLength : -1,
    data : data_use.filter(({basin}) => basin != 'Island Total'),
    columns : column_name,
    dom : 'lfrtip',
    responsive : true,
    destroy : true,
    searching: true,
    drawCallback: () => {
      const totals = data_use.find(({basin}) => basin == 'Island Total');
      const bottomRowHtml = '<tr>'+Object.values(totals).reduce((r,e) => r+=`<td>${e}</td>`,'')+'<td><button>Edit</button></td></tr>';
      $('#datatable tbody').append(bottomRowHtml);
    }
});
```

```html
<!doctype html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" /><script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script></head><body><table id="datatable"></table></body></html>
```

Comment: I'm not an expert is JS, when you call the `drawCallBacck` option, can you explain me this symbol : `=>` ?

Comment: [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option specifies the function (using [arrow syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in this case), that is triggered upon each table re-draw (caused by sorting, filtering, whatever). Above function extracts 'totals' row from the source data array, turns that object into HTML markup of the last table row (`<tr>` node) and appends that HTML to the `<tbody>` DOM node.

Answer (score 1):

Using [`initComplete`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete) which fires after table has fully been initialised

```
initComplete: function(settings, json) {
   var api = this.api()
   var tr = api.rows(function(idx, data, node) {
     return data.basin === 'Island Total';
   })
   $(api.table().node()).append(
     $('<tfoot></tfoot>').html(tr.nodes())
   );
   tr.remove();
}
```

```js
const data_use = [{basin:"Beaufond",yield:66,area:5183,production:342041},{basin:"Boid Rouge",yield:72.1,area:4848,production:349530},{basin:"Grand-Bois",yield:80.5,area:3519,production:238200},{basin:"Island Total",yield:73.3,area:20220,production:1481237},{basin:"Le Gol",yield:82.9,area:4282,production:354983},{basin:"Savanna",yield:63.4,area:2388,production:151483}];

const column_name = [{title:"Basin",data:"basin"},{title:"Yield (T/ha)",data:"yield"},{title:"Surface area (ha)",data:"area"},{title:"Production (T)",data:"production"},{title:"",data:()=>"<button>Edit</button>"}];;

$('#datatable').DataTable({
  sPaginationType: "full_numbers",
  lengthMenu: [
    [5, 10, 20, 30, -1],
    [5, 10, 20, 30, "All"]
  ],
  iDisplayLength: -1,
  data: data_use,
  columns: column_name,
  dom: 'lfrtip',
  responsive: true,
  destroy: true,
  searching: true,
  initComplete: function(settings, json) {
    var api = this.api()
    var tr = api.rows(function(idx, data, node) {
      return data.basin === 'Island Total';
    })
    $(api.table().node()).append(
      $('<tfoot></tfoot>').html(tr.nodes())
    );
    tr.remove();
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.js"></script>

<table id="datatable"></table>
```

Comment: This method it's work but the edit option is disable on the total line.

Comment: @SebCollard could you post a fiddle for that?

Answer (score 1):

can use the [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) function in dataTable which is a function that is called every time DataTables performs a draw.

Inside the function we can access all the data in the `dataTable`

```
 drawCallback: function () {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes(); // fetches all rows in the table

            // Loops through every row
            // group: first column value : basin
            // i: row count
            // currTable: all table data
            api.column(0, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i, currTable) {

                // Fetches the current index row data
                $currentRow = currTable.rows(rows[i]._DT_RowIndex).data()[0];

                if ($currentRow[0] === "Island Total") {
                    var rowCopy = rows[i]; // copy of the exact row
                    rows[i].remove(); // remove the row

                    // append the row to the end of the table
                    $('#datatable tbody').append(rowCopy);
                }
            });
        }
```

Inside the `drawCallback` we can also run any type of calculations depends on each data in the table.

```js
var data_use = [
    ["le gold", 77.5, 10190, 789666],
    ["bois rouge", 68.9, 10031, 691571],
    ["total île", 73.2, 20221, 1481237],
    ["Island Total", 63.3, 40221, 2891237],
];

$('#datatable').dataTable({
    fixedheader: true,
    responsive: true,
    data: data_use,
    columns: [
        { title: "Basin" },
        { title: "Yield (T/ha)" },
        { title: "Surface Area (ha)" },
        { title: "Production (T)" },
        {
            title: "Action",
            data: null,
            render: function (data, type, full) {

                return '<button class="btn btn-small btn-default">Edit</button>';
            }
        },
    ],
    columnDefs: [
        { bSortable: false, targets: 4, aTargets: ['nosort'] },
    ],
    dom: 'lfrtip',
    order: [[0, "asc"]],
    pagingtype: "simple",
    pagelength: 10,
    drawCallback: function () {
        var api = this.api();
        var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();

        api.column(0, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i, currTable) {

            $currentRow = currTable.rows(rows[i]._DT_RowIndex).data()[0];

            if ($currentRow[0] === "Island Total") {
                var rowCopy = rows[i];
                rows[i].remove();

                $('#datatable tbody').append(rowCopy);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.3.1/dt-1.10.18/rg-1.1.0/datatables.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="datatable"></table>
```